# How to specify a certain year in a senctence?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is/are the right way(s) to express a certain year in a sentence? I would be really appreciated if the explanations can be provide at the same time.

1.) ... in 2013

2.) ... in the year of 2013

3.) ... in the year 2013

Or any better choice?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

'In 2013' is perfectly sufficient. All the other examples just add unnecessary 'fluff'.

Comment: In context, that fluff may serve well though. If I write that of the 1995 samples taken in 1991, 1993 were tested positive, were-as in in a retest in 1993, 1991 were positive, but sample 1994 had disappeared , supposedly in 1992, and in 1995 some contamination had been found, _some_ readers might get a bit confused if I do not explicitly mention which numbers are years... Was that last 1995 a year or a sample?

Comment: As no context was provided, I didn't see fit to add it myself. But your point is taken.

Comment: @oerkelens in very rare cases a four-digit number **other than the year** will follow *in*

Comment: @MaulikV and yet I came up with one in seconds :) But even without the _in_, four digit number in commonly used year-ranges can be confusing. The same goes for years that are out of our comfortzone: _In 82, grandpa was considered important_ may not immediately be picked up as a headline to a story about a recently discovered Roman letter - many would just see an error. In this case the "fluff" _In 82 A.D._ would clarify a lot. The same goes for _Zager and Evans'_ [_in the year 2525_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izQB2-Kmiic)

Comment: @oerkelens I would certainly not write it that way. If I'm talking about the sample, either I'd use *in 100th* if I refer to the 100th sample. Or the better would be *in sample 100* which denotes that the sample is **named** 100 and not necessarily the 100th one. And as I said, use *a four-digit number* with *in* and it'll talk about the year in most of the contexts. :) I'm too young to think about 82 A.D. though haha!

Comment: So you add the fluff to the sample number instead of the year. Same difference, no? ;)

Comment: Isn't option 2) incorrect?

Comment: But are the 2nd and 3rd option grammatically correct?

Comment: Can anyone please answer me?:(

Comment: Technically 2 and 3 are grammatically correct, but you'd almost never see 2 'in the wild'.